# Floating divs 100 width when on separate line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following floating layout:

[image]

The two inner divs (red + green) should be placed next to each other using 60% and 40% of the outer divs total width.

Whenever the window is resized such that the green and red content does not fit on one row, each inner div should ge its own row having 100% of the outer div's width.

edit:
I do not know, when resizing should be donw. This depends on the div's content. In my case 2 dynamically created tables. Whenever the tables can be shown next to each other they should be placed on 1 row. Whenever they don't (because of too many columns, to long texts etc.) they should be broken on two lines. A media solution (with fixed breakpoints therefore do not help me here). Don't know if this is possible using css only or I do need to include some js here?

Is this reachable using css / html only?

Comment: sure - use media queries.

Comment: I think I didn't make this clear enough. The breakpoint isn't known in advance. The width at which the div should break depends on its content. In my case it's a table which is created dynamically. Whenever the table's content does not fit into the div anymore (because the entries / headers / columns are too width to place the two tables next too each other), the div should break on another line.

Comment: I agree with Johannes' suggestion of using media queries. However, this also seems like it could possibly be solved using flex boxes. (*Although, that is just an initial thought and I don't personally have the CSS knowledge to readily achieve that.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get pretty close with flexbox layout, but the width of the two rows won't be the same when wrap and scroll happens at the same time. I think you'll need to use media queries or Javascript to get that fixed if needed.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
}
.item-1 {
  background: aqua;
  flex: 1 1 60%;
}
.item-2 {
  background: gold;
  flex: 1 1 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-1">
    <div style="width:600px;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2">
    <div style="width:400px;">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lbnz2rx/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just media queries to achieve it. You can use another CSS file where you can save all your CSS for mobile(including iPad and tablets) sizes.
You can use also CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap, foundation and materializecssm they have already solution to that case.

Sample:

```css
//mobiles
@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .red{width:100%} 
  .green{width:100%}
}
//mobiles to ipad/tablet
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   .red{width:100%} 
   .green{width:100%} 
}

//laptop
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .red{width:60%} 
    .green{width:40%}
}
//small monitors
@media (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1059px) {
    .red{width:60%} 
    .green{width:40%}
}
//standard to large monitors
@media (min-width: 1060px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .red{width:60%} 
    .green{width:40%}
}
//large monitors
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .red{width:60%} 
    .green{width:40%}
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I dont think media queries solve my problem here. I just edited my initial question to make this a bit more clear.